# how to force GLUT to redraw the scene before the function returns?

Tags: opengl, glut

I have an OpenGL project which loads an object file, after the object is loaded i want to be able to move it with keyboard smoothly, so i wrote this block of code to do the job:

```
while (remains) {
    if (x_remains) {
        refPosition[0] += speed.x;
        if (refPosition[0] > nextPos[0]) {
            x_remains = false;
        }
    }
    if (y_remains) {
        refPosition[1] += speed.y;
        if (refPosition[1] > nextPos[1]) {
            y_remains = false;
        }
    }
    if (z_remains) {
        refPosition[2] += speed.z;
        if (refPosition[2] >= nextPos[2]) {
            z_remains = false;
        }
    }

    remains = x_remains || y_remains || z_remains;        
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

as you see I want to redisplay the scene in the while but when this is executed glutpostredisplay() just sets a flag and the scene is redrawn in the next iteration of the mainloop. my question is how can I redraw the scene before next loop of the while and before the function returns

Comment: What function is this `while` loop in?

Comment: Usually you use the idle function instead of a while loop for that. You can switch the idle function any time, so to support different "iteration" modes.

Comment: this while is in the keyboard callback function named keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You won't lose performance or see jerky rendering by going through glutPostRedisplay instead of drawing directly. (Or, if every microsecond really is that precious, why the heck are you using GLUT to begin with?)

On some systems you CAN'T draw outside the display function anyway, because the GL context won't be valid.

This is not unique to GLUT either. All the modern graphics/GUI toolkits I'm familiar with also require you to have a designated display function that gets invoked by an event handler, whether it's WM_PAINT messages, NSView drawRect:, or whatever.

If your program is not updating smoothly, it will be for some other reason.

Comment: you said why i am using glut, what should I use instead of it? I want to be able to redraw my scene in a loop..